# Using task when log4mongo add field to mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, log4net

I use [log4mongo-net](https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-net) to record my log into mongodb. And I want to minimize the time ellapsed during database writing, so that LOG would not effect my business method executing time.

Is that OK I change source code (log4mongo-net/MongoDBAppender.cs), **putting mongdb filed-add method in a task**:

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    var collection = GetCollection();
    collection.InsertOneAsync(BuildBsonDocument(loggingEvent));
    CreateExpiryAfterIndex(collection);
}
```

into

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var collection = GetCollection();
        collection.InsertOneAsync(BuildBsonDocument(loggingEvent));
        CreateExpiryAfterIndex(collection);
    });
}
```

Is there any side effect?

Comment: but it anyway is doing its work using async.. so why you want to add it onto a separate thread, you wont gain anything by doing this

Comment: @entre because when I run test, I find insert log into mongodb in a remote server costs too much time (nearly 200mm)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that your should write a test to see if you have impact on the performance. Creating extra threads can give a lot extra work. However when looking at your code and in the appender code, it can have better performance because of the GetCollection and CreateExpiryAfterIndex. These are now done in sync. I do not see any nasty side effects as result of your code.